# Alternative representation of affine map

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I would like to prove the following statement. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary and $\emptyset \neq S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\phi : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is affine iff there exists $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n, \beta$, each of them $\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i \ + \beta$, for all $x \in S.$

I am familiar with the fact that, provided that $0 \in S$,  $\phi \in \mathbb{R}^S$ is affine iff $\phi - \phi(0)$ is a linear map on $S$ and I believe this will be useful.

Comment: Is $S$ just an arbitrary subset? Or should it be an affine subspace?

Comment: It is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: certainly $S$ has to be affine set.

Comment: @Redshoes not really... There's a perfectly good notion of an affine function on $\mathbb R^n$ restricted to an arbitrary subset. If you really wanted to, you could even define this notion "intrinsically" using, say, the metric on $S$. As to whether this is a *useful* notion, I don't know. But it's certainly not a meaningless one.

Comment: If  $S$ is not an affine set then $\phi$ can be naturally and uniquely extended  to an affine function on entire $aff (S)$. So there is no points and no advantages of considering affine functions on non affine sets.  @DustanLevenstein

Comment: @Redshoes I didn't say there would be any advantage to it. I just said it's a perfectly well-defined idea. The fact that every affine function on an arbitrary subset canonically extends to its affine span has no bearing on the question of whether there's any value to the notion. Many incredibly fruitful ideas appear at a first glance to be vacuous or readily reduced to another case.

Comment: I originally took the statement above from my professor's problem set. I recently found it in Ok, Efe A. - Real Analysis with Economic Applications (p. 291 at the pdf version I had acces to) and indeed the proposition does not require S to be an affine set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what definition of affine you're given, but I'm guessing it'll be helpful for you to know this fact:

Fix a choice of $v_0 \in S$. Then $\phi$ is affine if and only if the function $$S-v_0 \to \mathbb R$$ given by $$w \mapsto \phi(w+v_0)$$ is affine. Here $S-v_0$ denotes the set $\{v-v_0\mid v \in S\}$.

This reduces your problem to understanding that transformation between $S$ and $S-v_0$ and handling the case $0 \in S$. See if you can prove that and then use it together with the fact you quoted.